# Google tag manager- No user property available for "item_id" and no default value was defined. Returning "undefined"

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, universal-analytics

I am trying to integrate Firebase analytics and Google tag manager into my Android app. I have configured some tags and triggers over my GTM console. But i see the following error in my debug console in Android studio. What i am trying to achieve is send my events to both Firebase analytics, GTM and then push the same event to Google analytics using Google tag manager. My events are successfully pushed to Firebase analytics, but not to Google analytics.

**Firebase event tracking:**

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("screen_name", "Main activity");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("screenview", params);
```

**Debug log:**

```
04-06 21:27:19.701 14388-23135/com.droidowl.googletagmanager V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1495667
04-06 21:27:21.098 14388-23135/com.droidowl.googletagmanager D/FA: Passing event to registered event handler (FE): screenview, Bundle[{screen_name=Main activity}]
04-06 21:27:21.103 14388-14829/com.droidowl.googletagmanager D/FA: Fetching user attributes (FE)
04-06 21:27:21.109 14388-23135/com.droidowl.googletagmanager V/FA: Using measurement service
04-06 21:27:21.109 14388-23135/com.droidowl.googletagmanager V/FA: Connecting to remote service
04-06 21:27:21.157 14388-23135/com.droidowl.googletagmanager D/FA: Connected to remote service
04-06 21:27:21.158 14388-23135/com.droidowl.googletagmanager V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
04-06 21:27:21.170 14388-14829/com.droidowl.googletagmanager W/GoogleTagManager: No user property available for "item_id" and no default value was defined. Returning "undefined".
04-06 21:27:21.174 14388-14829/com.droidowl.googletagmanager W/GoogleTagManager: No user property available for "item_id" and no default value was defined. Returning "undefined".
04-06 21:27:21.179 14388-23135/com.droidowl.googletagmanager D/FA: Logging event (FE): screenview, Bundle[{screen_name=Main activity, _o=app+gtm}]
04-06 21:27:26.190 14388-23135/com.droidowl.googletagmanager V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
```

Play services version: 9.4.0